# What would happen if I am doing my PhD on a topic and I find a very recent paper with the results I was obtaining?

Tags: publications, thesis, mathematics, ethics, publishability

I am doing my Ph.D. in maths and working on something. However, I was wondering what would happen if someone publishes similar results to the ones I am obtaining while I am working on that.  I have no control over that because it may happen that the result is totally new and therefore I couldn't check before starting to work. Will all the time spent being lost? Are my results valid for defending my dissertation?

Comment: As I understand it, in the math community, the method of proof is more important.  If you have a different approach to proving the same result that is useful, then there is no worry.  I think it's quite rare to have exactly the same approach unless you are looking over another person's shoulder.